# Unit testing lit-element mixins

Tags: unit-testing, lit-element

What are the ways to unit test a lit-element mixin? I have a simple mixin that just modifies the `firstUpdated` lifecycle event of a lit-element:

```
const mixin = sup => class extends sup {
  firstUpdated() {
    super.firstUpdated();
    // do something else.
  }
}
```

So basically, the usage is:

```
class MyElement extends mixin(LitElement) {
  ...
}
```

I'm not really sure how to handle the unit tests for this.

**UPDATE**

I could probably create a test element that extends the mixin, i.e. `MyElement`, and then test the element's firstUpdated function. Is that the only way to test this or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a test element class to apply the mixin to is the right approach. There are two ways to think about mixins that show this:

1. A mixin is only a potential class - you don't actually have anything to test until you apply it to a superclass to generate a concrete class.
2. A mixin is a function. You need to call a function to test it.